# Firewall and VPN

Tags: vpn, firewalls

Let's suppose i work in a small office and i can't use my workstation to navigate in Facebook because the external firewall forbids it. But i still can use a VPN to bypass the firewall.

I read that that it's possible to integrate VPN with the firewall, in this case could the security administrator set the external firewall in a way that it blocks access to Facebook even if i'm using a VPN ?

Comment: Depending on the Firewall the admin can block VPNs in general

Comment: What's the purpose of integrating a Firewall with VPN ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be conflating two different ways that VPN's are used:

1)  Corporate VPN's are often used by companies to enable their employees to work remotely.  When an employee is working remotely, he/she can connect to the company's network through a VPN.  Then, it's as if the user is on the 'trusted' side of the firewall, and it's as if they are on the company's network.  They can access other resources (e.g. network file servers, etc.) on the network.  Also, any outside connections will appear to be coming from the network's public IP address.  This is normally what people mean when they refer to a VPN integrated with a firewall.

2)  VPN services allow users to route their network connection through the VPN service's network.  User's typically use a VPN service to make their internet connection appear to be originating from an IP other than their own, for privacy reasons.  Or, users can use a VPN service to 'bypass' blocks on outgoing connections from the network that they are on to certain services (like Facebook).  The connection to the VPN is typically encrypted, so anyone/anything monitoring your traffic on your local network will have no way of knowing that sites you are accessing through the VPN.

So in your case, if you were on your company's network, and you wanted to access Facebook, you could try connecting to a VPN provider, and you may succeed in getting around your company's block on Facebook this way.  This is basically (2), above.  However, this is not the same way of using a VPN as described in (1) above, which is the case where a VPN is integrated with a firewall, typically used for allowing remote access to the network.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about bypassing security controls. This is a sackable offense, if not worse.

Anyway, academically speaking, if you can VPN out, you can usually bypass local network controls.

However any controls imposed on the computer you're using (even if you can run a VPN) would still be enforced in the same way, so you could still have your browsing controlled by local security software or an external proxy.

2nd part of your question is confusing and suggests that perhaps you are not grasping the basics of networking, security controls, VPNs, etc. If you're connected to a VPN peer on the Internet, your corp firewall will see nothing but an encrypted data stream between your computer and the VPN server.